# PDF and Excel styling with datatable buttons extension in shiny

Tags: r, pdf, datatable, shiny

I use buttons extension in my shiny application. How can I download pdf with same styling like it is done in application? Because I have the app looking like that

[image]

but when I download my table to the pdf it doesn't have that styling and looks like that:

[image]

the same with downloading excels, I have thousand separator in app and it downloads without it.  I suppose that the same function do it for both but I don't know which.